# Unable to redirect even after 302 response in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I using doing post call using Ajax.

```
    $.ajax({
        url : link,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data, textStatus) {
            alert("success");
        }
    });
```

Server is returning 302 response, with Location value in response header.
Following is the response header(settling google.com as location for testing)

```
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Length  55
Content-Type    text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Date    Sun, 09 Nov 2014 09:28:50 GMT
Location    https://www.google.com
Vary    Accept
```

Still still is not redirecting to google.com.
Also still it "not" going into success handler.
Looks like I am missing something obvious.

Comment: Yes, You've missed the fact that such redirect violate [Same-origin_policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: In other words you cannot follow redirects to external domains in JS

Comment: ok..actually it is not happening for same domain also. And shouldn't it come to success handler after completion.?

Comment: Emm, do you want to reload in the page you're sending the AJAX request the redirected page? what do you exactly want to do?